# IntelliJ "Cannot infer Scala class path..." but Gradle testCompile is correct?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I've got a Spring Boot project building through Gradle that recently saw the addition of some Gatling tests.  The Gatlings stuff, which needs Scala support, is all down in src/test/scala.  The build.gradle file got a new testCompile dependency to support it and, from a gradle perspective, all is well...

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
...
dependencies {
  ...
  testCompile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1"
  testCompile "io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:2.2.5"
  ...
}
```

The gradle docs suggest that testCompile is all we need here:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html

IntelliJ is unhappy with this configuration insisting

```
Warning:<i><b>root project 'tenderfoot': Unable to build Scala project configuration</b>
Details: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Cannot infer Scala class path because no Scala library Jar was found. Does root project 'tenderfoot' declare dependency to scala-library? Searched classpath: configuration ':compileClasspath'.</i>
```

If I lift the dependency up from `testCompile` to `compile`, the intellij warning goes away, but now my spring boot uber jar thing is unnecessarily bloated.

What's the way out?  How do I get IntelliJ to stop Warning on this?

Is this actually an IntelliJ bug?

Comment: Simple dude change : testCompile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1" to compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1"

Comment: @Aravinth yeah...I know.  Now may already bloated Spring Boot JAR is further huge due to IntelliJ bug.  Qwality!

Comment: Okay then close this one

Comment: If you're using scala, then it should be in your uber jar. Perhaps you could manage with a non-uber jar instead though.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem also (having to set the dependency manually from IntelliJ).

I "fixed" it by setting the dependency as `compileOnly` as opposed to `compile`, this scope does not include the JAR in the final distribution.

The code I use is (please note that my dependency includes Scala as a transitive dependency):

```
    compileOnly("io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:$gatlingVersion")
```